# How to make torn edges in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

My idea is ->create an ellipse ->fill it with a radial gradient fill -> add noise.
Last step for edges is unknown for me.

**Original**

[image]

**My**

[image]

Comment: is your ellipse a vector shape or just a raster layer?

Comment: The final image should be a raster.

Comment: Rather than torn edges, it's more like blue watercolor on a heavily textured paper.

Comment: Hi, I put this on hold because as evident by the current answers its not clear which part you're struggling with. Is it the shape of the ellipse you want to have imperfections on or is the texture you're not happy with? Please [edit] your question to clarify

Comment: The texture of the original comes from being a scanned print with halftone screen. So if this is for offset print, the texture will come by itself. It will only be as visible if the artwork is small enough though.

Answer (score 3):

A simple method would be to use the Brush Tool, with white as the foreground colour, set to full opacity, and with a soft edge. Then manually paint an irregular edge around the ellipse.

[image]

Comment: irregular borders require irregular methods...

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for irregularity in the ellipse you would need to do it by hand (erase parts of the ellipsee with soft brush with irregular shape) before doing any step I've mentioned below.
The effect came from printing with (usually) one or two color machines. It's the raster that make a gradient that is showing.

So step 1, make an ellipse and fill it with black to white gradient (note: it shouldn't be a shape but a fill made to marquee selection). The ellipse should be a circle that you drag into ellipse shape after fill. 
[image]

Then change the Image mode to Grayscale and then Bitmap. In the first pop-up window Set output to something around 1000 pixels/inch and method to Halftone Screen. In my screen I've set resolution to only 150 just to see if the next step will be visible (it's not).
[image]

In next step set frequency to something that will look good in your desired media (print or screen. To simulate the size use proper setting in the View menu). I've chosen 10 lines/inch, zero degrees angle (**NOTE** In your picture the angle of the halftone is exactly 15 degrees as this is cyan which, if printed from C plate, will always be skewed by that amount) and of course Ellipse shape (round might also works). 
[image]

Now the result should look like this. You can see the difference in moiré pattern between screen and navigator window.

[image]

Then just go back to Image mode Grayscale and RGB and use Adjustment to set the desired color.

Answer (score 0):

From the Ellipse layer, load the ellipse selection and make a mask.

Add a filter minimum to this mask and a gaussian blur.

[image]